# Colorbox item-specific div below/next-to image

Tags: jquery, customization, colorbox

I've found this question on StackOverflow 
[Adding div below images in colorbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957886/adding-div-below-images-in-colorbox)

But it explains how to put a generic (one for all images) div below image,
what if i want to display some image specific information?

Is there a way to know from a callback the item it's going to show?

Comment: Try to pass thrue get an id to your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to know from a callback the item it's going to show?

This is exactly what it did when it referenced `$.colorbox.element()`. Notice that the text shown each time was unique to each link.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realized it was returning the current item at each call.